# Sandboxing (gVisor or Kata Containers) for Azure Kubernetes Service to run untrusted code

Tags: azure, security, azure-aks

I'm looking to build a solution that is very similar to what Azure DevOps or any CI/CD product has, which, takes user submitted executable's, code, PowerShell/cmd commands, etc. executes them to deploy applications. Essentially I had the untrusted code execution problem.

1. Needs to be multi-tenant. Complete isolation from other tenants
2. There could be 500+ tenants.

I see that Google Cloud has [GKE Sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/sandbox/) which is a possible solution, but I was hoping for something in Azure instead.

Is it possible to use Kata Containers or gVisor for AKS so I can have kernel level isolate between containers?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the user containers in ACI which has hypervisor isolation, managed by Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview#hypervisor-level-security

And integrates with AKS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-scale#burst-to-azure-container-instances

Comment: Containers can talk to other containers within a container group and the hyper-v isolation only applies to container groups not all the containers inside of them. Container groups have 100 container limit which might not be enough. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups

Comment: You should edit your question and add this requirement

Comment: You can have additional container groups is you want more granular isolation.

Comment: I have added the additional requirements. Hopefully that makes more sense.